# Error when MySQLx tries to parse an expression (Nodejs)

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, npm-install

I have downloaded the @mysql/xDevApi from NPM repository 
 [@mysql/xdevapi](http://npmjs.com/package/@mysql/xdevapi) and its version is 1.0.5

**I am getting errors after trying out 2 different ways:-**

1. collection.find("$.name == :name") .bind('name','Test') 
   -> Here it is giving name is undefined
2. collection.find(name == :name") .bind('name','Test') 
   ->Here it is giving "Expecting '.', '(', got 'like'" error

Any idea on how to use this and which is the correct one? Or is there any other solution? I need to bind parameters.

Kindly suggest! Thank You!

Comment: [Bug #84584 Unable to bind parameters](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84584).

Answer (score 0):

This is the way suggested by the documentation provided--

var myRes = collection.find('name = :name').bind('name','Test').execute();

Reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/parameter-binding.html

Comment: Yes. I have implemented in same manner as mentioned in documentation.  But it does not seems to work

Comment: @TanviShah On you (2) you excepting '.','(' because u forget to add ' " ' after the parenthesis and before.

Comment: :-  Actually here it is syntax error...and in my code it is correctly defined... but still its not working.